# Azure API Run Command - Accepted 202 response

Tags: azure, rest, api

I am trying to use the Microsoft Azure Rest API Run Command:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual%20machines%20run%20commands/runcommand

I eventually want to pass a fairly complex PowerShell script but I am trying a simple "ipconfig" command to test the connection but I cannot get anything but a HTTP 202 response which returns no json response data (this is as per the API).

The login and OAuth steps work correctly and I can successfully GET VM and other service management data which require the same authorization scope.

Has anyone successfully used this API and any ideas why I am only getting a 202 response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal, when got `202` response, you need to call another api to check the result.

In your case, you will get a response header like below, just call the api in the `location`(also need the Authorization Bearer token).

[image]

I test it in the postman, it works fine.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this doc - [Track asynchronous Azure operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-async-operations), and see this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-async-operations#example-requests-and-responses).

Comment: I wasted a few hours, glad I found your answer. One more thing I was not able to do. I used this with `runCommand` endpoint but I'm not able to control the status response and have anything in there, it is always the same except when the PowerShell script I'm executing with the `RunCommand` through exception I get the exception in the second `value.message` any ideas how can I return my message or even make it fail?