# Images not getting deleted in Azure even after getting success status code using REST API in C#

Tags: c#, azure, rest

I am using the API: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subId}/resourceGroups/{rgName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/{imageName}?api-version=2019-03-01` to delete the Images. Here's the code (the code is executed in a loop of list of Images):

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); //obtained from https://management.azure.com/
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseManagementUri); //https://management.azure.com/
    using (var responseGet = client.DeleteAsync(api).Result)
    {
        if (responseGet.IsSuccessStatusCode) //returns true and status code is 202
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Deleted {resourceUri}");
        }
        else
        {
            log.LogWarning($"Failed to deleted {resourceUri}\n{responseGet.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result}");
        }
    }
}
```

The responseGet contains: `StatusCode: 202, ReasonPhrase: 'Accepted', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent`, `StatusCode:    Accepted`.

When I check the Azure Portal or `GET` [list of images using REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/images/list), I can see the Image is still present.
But when I run the same code for deleting the snapshot it gets deleted successfully. I use the same API for snapshot and looks like this: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subId}/resourceGroups/{rgName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/{snapshotName}?api-version=2019-03-01`.
What should I do for deleting the Image?

Comment: If I run the code for multiple times, the Image gets deleted!

Comment: Yes I understood the purpose - and I hope it would work; I am trying to implement the same by reading the docs (the link you provided). Thanks. I would mark it as answer once I test it.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: the docs were really helpful, and thanks for the info on 202 status code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different REST APIs will return different results, when you get the `202 (Accepted)`, the operation will not be completed immediately, you need to call another API like below to check the progress.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{region}/operations/{operation-id}?api-version=2016-03-30
```

Please check this doc - [`Track asynchronous Azure operations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-async-operations) and this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-async-operations#example-requests-and-responses), also a [similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844270/azure-api-run-command-accepted-202-response/56844669#56844669).