# How to get all the services available in a Azure Virtual Machine using REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Using power shell, we can connect to azure virtual machine and execute **Get-Service** command to list all the services. Is there a way to fetch data using REST API?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Joy Wang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this REST API - [`Virtual Machines Run Commands - Run Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual%20machines%20run%20commands/runcommand) to run `Get-Service` in the VM, then you could get the services.

Request URL:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/runCommand?api-version=2019-07-01
```

Request body:

```
{
  "commandId": "RunPowerShellScript",
  "script": [
    "Get-Service"
  ]
}
```

When you call the REST API, you will get a `202` status code, there is no response in the body, you need to call another api in the `Location` of the header to check the result, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56844669/9455659).

[image]

Check the result via call another REST API:

[image]

Comment: I am getting overflow dots in the command response (Ex: WindosAzureGue...). How can i resolve this ?

Comment: @karthik_varma_k Where did you call the rest api? If in the postman, there is a line feed button, it may solve the issue.

Comment: How long it will take to get the response ? In my environment, it is taking approx. 2 mins. Will it depend on any factors like type of VMs etc..?

Comment: @karthik_varma_k Not sure, maybe.

Comment: The script response contains only some data not all (got only 34 services out of 221 services ). Any idea?